# Xcode 4.5 null sign identity

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

With update on xcode 4.5 I have got some strange problem.
When I try to build *.ipa for testers, and choose identity to sign build, I see next:

[image]

Problem with "AppName distr Store (from '(null)', for com.app.name)"
App build with "null" identity don't installing on device over the air.
Before 4.5 I have never seen "null", and I don't know what to do. Help me please.

PS:From Russia with love. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, and the provisioning profiles are otherwise valid. I'm assuming it's an Xcode UI bug for now.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue, but when I try it in Xcode 4.4.1, the from field is correct

Comment: I get the same. I've tried `refreshing` (bottom of the menu) but no luck with that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not reproduced bug in Xcode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503) 
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing (deleting) all you provisioning profiles from xcode and re-downloading them?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to reinstall all provision profiles and other *.cer, *.p12 files. Not helped :( 
(reinstall xcode not helped too).